# Jhipster CI (Jenkins 2 + Sonarqube) -> Memory Heap

Tags: docker, sonarqube, jhipster, jenkins-pipeline

I try to scan Jhipster generated code with Sonarqube during a Jenkins build.

My configuration is the following:

- Gitlab as Docker Container
- Jenkins 2 as Docker Container
- Sonarqube 5.4 (higher is not permitted with MariaDB; right?) as Docker Container

This is a fresh install and all systems are communicating together.

When running builds, Jenkins is alerting about duplicates references in the 'bower_components' repository.

> WARN: Too many duplication references on file
>   [moduleKey=Challenge1:0.1-HENDRIX,
>   relative=src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_vun-tz.js,
>   basedir=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Challenge-1] for block at line 20.
>   Keep only the first 100 references.

My problem is that I do not get the reasons why is alerting about it since few exclusions have been set at different levels:

1) Within pom.xml

```
<sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/content/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*, target/www/**/*.*</sonar.exclusions>
```

2) Within Jenkinsfile

```
node {
    ...
    stage 'scan'
    sh "${sonarqubeScannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9000 -Dsonar.projectKey=Challenge1:'0.1-HENDRIX' -Dsonar.projectName='Challenge 1' -Dsonar.projectVersion='0.1-HENDRIX' -Dsonar.sources='src/' -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions=**/bower_components/**"
}
```

3) On sonarqube customizing itself (Analysis Scope).

EDIT:
This "non-exclusion" was originally leading to a memory dump that I could solved by extending the memory on sonarqube (sonar.properties).

```
sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

However, I a still am afraid that extending memory isn't the appropriate solution and I must be able to exclude some parts of code. What should I do to remove bower components from the scan analysis? (I probably made something wrong).

Comment: What's the question? The server error indicates that you run out of memory there. Why not increase the memory allocation?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support. Actually, it has been extended from 512Mb to 2Gb w/o success. I am afraid that Sonarqube doesn't exclude some folders like bower_components leading to the dump. Looking some advices...

Comment: please [edit] your question to make clear 1) exactly what the question _is_ and 2) what you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake: I was using -Dsonar.coverage.exclusions instead of -Dsonar.global.exclusions